# importlib not working for files in subdirectory

Tags: python, python-3.7, python-importlib

I have a directory structure like this :

```
__init__.py
test.py
dir1/
    __init__.py
    dir2
        __init__.py
        myfile.py
```

There might be more py files inside dir2. So I want to import them at run time and load all classes defined inside these files.

test.py:

```
import inspect
import importlib

module = importlib.import_module('dir1/dir2/myfile.py')
for name, obj in inspect.getmembers(module):
    if inspect.isclass(module):
        print(obj.id)   # id is defined in all the classes
```

This gives me error while doing import_module :

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dir1/dir2/myfile'

I've tried to append dir1/dir2 path to sys.path and then import myfile.py, which doesn't work either. Also the similar code works is myfile.py is placed at same level as test.py.

Python version : 3.7

Comment: the folder which contain test.py and dir1 should also have `__init__.py`

Comment: Why not use `from dir1.dir2 import myfile as module`?

Comment: Yes, __init__.py is present alongside test.py, and I've mentioned __init__.py inside dir1 in my question.

Comment: @IainShelvington as I said, there might be multiple files inside dir2, which I'm not aware of.

Comment: `import_module()` accepts dotted module paths, not filenames.

Comment: As @AKX says you need to pass the dotted path to the file to be imported `importlib.import_module('dir1.dir2.myfile')`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just reiterating for the sake of clarity:

`import_module()` only accepts dotted module paths, not filenames. E.g., `importlib.import_module('dir1.dir2.myfile')`

Comment: Yes, figured it out.